# Detect windows time change c++

Tags: c++-cli, ctime

I am using

```
CTime t = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
```

to get the current time from Winodws, but when the clock changes the next day and the application is still open, the time does not change. How can i make 't' be updated automatically when time changes?.

What i tried is to use TimeChanged event,

```
    public:
event EventHandler^ TimeChanged {
    static void add(EventHandler^ value);
    static void remove(EventHandler^ value);
}
```

but how to apply this on CTime t?. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Of course the time you fetch will not change. When you fetch the current time you get the *current* time at the time of the fetch. It will not update automatically, you have to fetch it again. Maybe you just want a simple timer that fires once every minute and (re-)fetches the current time?

Comment: And on a side note: according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) the `TimeChanged` event is raised "when the user changes the time on the system clock."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a simpler way, for example to use difftime to calculate difference between two times?. like compare time now and time before 1 minute. but how to do that syntax wise. I am a beginner in c++.

Comment: You're in C++/CLI, so you can use the `System::DateTime` type. For example, take `DateTime::Now` at the start of some slow processing, take another `DateTime::Now` at the end, subtract them and you obtain a `System::TimeSpan`...